# Extracting value from TextInput when passing it to a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following where the TextInput passes the value of the input to a function. My question is how to I extract the text value from the searchString that is passed to the function. At the minute it is an object.

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder="Search..."
  onChangeText={(searchString) => this.searchChanged({searchString})}
  placeholderTextColor="#555"
/>

searchChanged(searchField) {

        console.log("Search String Changed "+ searchField);

        this.setState({ 
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.convertNeighbourArrayIntoMap(this.state.dataSourceCopy, "Mike")),
        });

    }
```

Comment: Firstly, you only need the argument in the second part of the onChange fx: `onChangeText={() => this.searchChanged({searchString})}` secondly you say "it's an object", what kind of object are you passing to it? Can you not directly access the property you need?

Comment: At the minute in the console log Im getting "Search String Changed [object Object]", I would like this to state the  text value of within the input that Im passing.

Answer (score 0):

It's an object because you pass an object:

```
{searchString} - means object
```

You should change code to this:

```
  onChangeText={(searchString) => this.searchChanged(searchString)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `{}` here:

```
this.searchChanged({searchString})
```

Meaning of `{searchString}` is `{searchString:searchString}`, And it will get converted into:

```
this.searchChanged({searchString: searchString})
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = 5;

console.log({a});
```

Write it like this:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChangeText={(searchString) => this.searchChanged(searchString)}
    placeholderTextColor="#555"
/>

searchChanged(searchField) {
    console.log("Search String Changed "+ searchField);
}
```